# Android selector layout of a menu item not working on a checkable item

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to make a favourite item in the menu that can display a hollow heart when unchecked and a solid one when checked

However the selector approach is not working, I managed to make it work in code with a boolean value that is toggled and a `item.setIcon()` method. But I want to understand why my selector approach didn't work.

here's what I tried:

- I tried to make a checkable attribute in the item xml with no luck
  also tried to set the setChecked directly from code checked the debugger the `item.isChecked()` is returning `true` as intended but the icon doesn't change
- tried to set the checked state from inside the xml to true to see if it will change icon still didn't work

The code is showing that the checking state is changing as intended but the selector is not responding by changing the icon accordingly the Question is why is that so and how to solve it.

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_contact"
        android:title="@string/action_contact"
        android:orderInCategory="10"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_order"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_shopping_cart"
        android:title="@string/action_order"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_status"
        android:title="@string/action_status"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_status_info"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favourites"
        android:title="@string/action_favourites"
        android:icon="@drawable/favourite_toggle_image"
        android:checkable="true"
        app:showAsAction="always" />


</menu>
```

favourite_toggle_image.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_favourite_info"
    android:state_checked="true" />

  <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_favourite_unchecked_info"
    android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

MainActivity.java

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_order:
                displayToast("Order");
                break;
            case R.id.action_status:
                displayToast("Status");
                break;
            case R.id.action_favourites:
                lastState = !lastState;

                //if (lastState)  item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favourite_info);
                //else if (!lastState)  item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_favourite_unchecked_info);

                item.setChecked(lastState);
                displayToast("Favourites");
                break;
            case R.id.action_contact:
                displayToast("Contact");
                break;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                displayToast("Settings");
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```